# How to delete nested state object in immutable-js inside reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, immutable.js

I want to delete an entity from `data` (which is List inside object `someData`). I am using `fromJS` of immutable js in my reducer to keep the state immutable

I tried using `updateIn, deleteIn, update, removeIn` and whatever I could find on immutable-js. But it didn't work for me. Most probably I am using these functions the wrong way.

```
import { fromJS, updateIn } from 'immutable';
import * as type from './constants';

export const initialState = fromJS({
  someData: [],
  loading: true,
});

function someReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case type.DELETE_SINGLE_ENTITY:
      updateIn(state, ['someData', 'data'], val =>
        val.filter(x => x.id !== action.id),      
      );
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default someReducer;

//example someData

/*
{
    date: "",
    data: [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "machine_type": "xyz",
            "created_time": "2019-06-18T10:36:60Z",
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": "22",
            "machine_type": "abc",
            "created_time": "2019-06-20T10:36:60Z",
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "machine_type": "kjhkh",
            "created_time": "2019-06-11T12:36:60Z",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
*/
```

I want to delete an entity matching with the id passed in action. 
Before deleting the output of `state.get('someData')` is in the above example. My expected output (when `action.id` is 2) when I type `state.get` should be:

```
{
    date: "",
    data: [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "machine_type": "xyz",
            "created_time": "2019-06-18T10:36:60Z",
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": "22",
            "machine_type": "abc",
            "created_time": "2019-06-20T10:36:60Z",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: just create a new object spreading out the state then also specify the someData property on the new object with the array returned from someData.filter

Comment: @21x37 My problem was little bit different I didn't want to do it by defensive cloning . Anyways thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally! Got it!
this:

```
      return updateIn(state, ['someData', 'data'], val =>
        val.filter(x => x.id !== action.id),      
      );
```

instead of this:

```
      updateIn(state, ['someData', 'data'], val =>
        val.filter(x => x.id !== action.id),      
      );
      return state;
```

Previously I thought updateIn would update the state itself but it doesn't it returns the updated object. So just returning the updateIn would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the filter function

```js
const sampleData = [{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3}]

const idToRemove = 2;

const updatedData = sampleData.filter(el => {
  return el.id !== idToRemove
})

console.log(updatedData);
```